# How do I set the option use_remote_estimate?

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-fdw

Where do I set the "Cost Estimation Options" for `postgres_fdw`. Specifically I want to add `use_remote_estimate`.

```
test=# SET use_remote_estimate=true;
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "use_remote_estimate"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`postgres_fdw` doesn't use [GUC variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/config-setting.html). The settings for `postgres_fdw` are actually set with *options* under [`CREATE SERVER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createserver.html),

```
CREATE SERVER [IF NOT EXISTS] server_name [ TYPE 'server_type' ] [ VERSION 'server_version' ]
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER fdw_name
    [ OPTIONS ( option 'value' [, ... ] ) ];
```

Or with [`ALTER SERVER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterserver.html)

> Change options for the server. `ADD`, `SET`, and `DROP` specify the action to be performed. ADD is assumed if no operation is explicitly specified. Option names must be unique; names and values are also validated using the server's foreign-data wrapper library.

Like,

```
-- Set it if it's never been set
ALTER SERVER flybase
  OPTIONS (ADD use_remote_estimate 'true');

-- Change it if it has been set
ALTER SERVER flybase
  OPTIONS (SET use_remote_estimate 'false');

-- Drop it if it has never been set
ALTER SERVER flybase
  OPTIONS (DROP use_remote_estimate);
```